# Disable translations for a given request (laravel)

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, internationalization

I'm currently building a Vue.js SPA with laravel as the backend where I need to support multiple locales. I'm therefore considering using [Lang.js](https://github.com/rmariuzzo/Lang.js) alongside laravel's built-in translation system to manage the translated stings. I basicly want to manage all the strings in laravel (on the backend) but let the frontend handle the actual translations, to allow the user to switch language dynamicly with a language switcher ui component.

The problem is that when I submit a form request that is validated on the server, the error messages are already translated, thus not allowing the frontend to pick a language on-the-fly.

My question is how I can disable the translation for a given request (preferably using headers in middleware or something like that) and instead print the raw translation keys

For example for the given validation

```php
<?php
function store() {
    request()->validate(['test' => 'required'])
}
```

The server returns

```
{
    'message': 'The given data was invalid',
    'errors': {
        'test': 'The test field is required'
    }
}
```

instead of

```
{
    'message': 'The given data was invalid',
    'errors': {
        'test': 'validation.required',
    }
}
```

I have already tried using `\App::setLocale('somethinginvalidandrandom')` which should technically try to translate the key into a language that doesn't exist, thus returning the key, but besides feeling wrong and hacky, this approach won't work if I want to preserve the fallback language funcionality of laravel, since the key would be found in the fallback language (en).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually just solved it myself, and thought to reply here in case others where trying to solve the same problem as me in the future.

## Solution

I added an `invalidJson` method to my `App\Exceptions\Handler` class, that Laravel will automaticly call whenever an `ValidationException` is thrown and `$request->wantsJson()` is true.

In that method i just checked if my custom header (`X-WITH-UNTRANSLATED-VALIDATION`) is present in the request with the value of "yes".
If that is the case i get the validator instance from the exception, and grab all the rules.

However laravel represent these rules internally in "studly caps case" (StartsWith) and we want to get them in a snake case format ("starts_with"). To fix this I used the laravel collection helpers to map over the nested array and convert the rule keys to snake case.

## Code

Here is the code from `app\Exceptions\Handler.php`.

```php
/**
 * Convert a validation exception into a JSON response.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException  $exception
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
protected function invalidJson($request, ValidationException $exception)
{
    //If the header is not present in the request 'no' wil be provided as the fallback value, thus not being equal with "yes"
    if($request->header('X-WITH-UNTRANSLATED-VALIDATION', 'no') === "yes") {
        $failed = $this->makeUntranslatedMessagesIntoSnakeCase($exception);

        return response([
            // Get the original exception message
            'message' => $exception->getMessage(),
            'errors' => $failed,
            // Add the original translated error messages under a diffrent key to help with debugging
            'translated_errors' => $exception->errors(),
        ], $exception->status);
    }

    //If the header is not present (with the right value) we return the default JSON response instead
    return parent::invalidJson($request, $exception);
}

/**
 * Convert the untranslated rule names of a validation exception into snake case.
 * 
 * @param \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException  $exception
 * @return array
 */
protected function makeUntranslatedMessagesIntoSnakeCase(ValidationException $exception) : array
{
    return collect($exception->validator->failed())->map(function ($item) {
        return collect($item)->mapWithKeys(function ($values, $rule) {
            return [Str::snake($rule) => $values];
        });
    })->toArray();
}
```

## Further improvements

If you need to disable translation for normal "non-json" requests, you can also override the `invalid` method in the Handler.php and do a similar thing, but just add the messages to the session instead. Likewise you could also add the translated messages alongside the untranslated messages.

## Edit

I also added `'translated_errors' => $exception->errors()`, to the response to help with debugging

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the answer you're looking for but you could implement an endpoint for switching languages in the backend. You can call this endpoint whenever you change language on the frontend. Additionally it allows you to save the selected language, so if a user were to exit the SPA and come back later the preferred language is not reset.

Comment: I just found a solution myself, but thanks for the answer anyways :D! This would be a valid approach in a server side rendered app, since the page would be fully refreshed on language change, but since the language can be switched after the error message has been posted, it would pose a problem, since the error message still would be in the first language.

Answer (score 0):

I personally find your solution a bit hacking for my taste.

My own approach on this one was to create a translator class that extends original `Translator`. Then, I did an override of method `get` and return key and format parameters.
Another thing I needed was to get a copy of `TranslatorServiceProvider` since `Translator` is instantiated in there. New provider must be registered in `config\app.php`.

`App\Providers\ApiTranslatorServiceProvider`

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\Common\ApiTranslator;
use Illuminate\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider;

class ApiTranslationServiceProvider extends TranslationServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->registerLoader();

        $this->app->singleton('translator', function ($app) {
            $loader = $app['translation.loader'];

            // When registering the translator component, we'll need to set the default
            // locale as well as the fallback locale. So, we'll grab the application
            // configuration so we can easily get both of these values from there.
            $locale = $app['config']['app.locale'];

            $trans = new ApiTranslator($loader, $locale);

            $trans->setFallback($app['config']['app.fallback_locale']);

            return $trans;
        });
    }
}
```

`App\Common\ApiTranslator`

```
<?php

namespace App\Common;

use Illuminate\Translation\Translator;

class ApiTranslator extends Translator
{
    /**
     * Get the translation for the given key.
     *
     * @param  string  $key
     * @param  array  $replace
     * @param  string|null  $locale
     * @param  bool  $fallback
     * @return string|array
     */
    public function get($key, array $replace = [], $locale = null, $fallback = true)
    {
        if (count($replace) > 0)
        {
            return ["key" => $key, "format" => $replace];
        }
        return $key;
    }
}
```

There are cases when Validator is trying to edit string message, and that is why a string is returned depending on the case.
As a result, ajax requests return an array of objects each one of which contain a translation key and values.